# How to express two variables changing simultaneously?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

In a function of one variable you can use a derivative to explain the rate of change of that function with respect to the one variable. Similarly in a multivariate function, you can use the partial derivative to explain the rate of change of that function with respect to one of its variables, holding all other variables constant.

How do you express the change in a function $f(x,y)$ when $x$ and $y$ change together? For example, if $f(x,y) = 2x + 2y$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2$, but this assumes only 1 variable is changing.  When $x$ and $y$ increase by 1 unit simultaneously, then the change in $f$ is always to "add $4$".

Can you express this using derivatives (e.g., by using something like $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x \partial y}=4)$ and if not, what method could I use?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative

Comment: @AnneBauval I think this is what was looking for. Thanks.